# How does Hibernate handle caching with NativeSQL calls?

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, jpa

I've got a need to run a NativeQuery insert command, without using my Hibernate entities.  But I have concerns how this will affect any caching (L1 / L2) that may be done.  From what I've read in blogs/etc it appears that Hibernate automatically flushes all caches as soon as it encounters any NativeQuery calls.

Is this true?  Knowing which tables I am manipulating with the native sql calls, am I able to disable Hibernate's automatic flushing and control specifically what to flush and what to maintain?  Can this be done via annotation, or must it be done through calls to the EntityManagerFactory.getCache().evict()?

Ex:

```
entityManager.createNativeQuery(
    "INSERT INTO JOIN_TABLE (CONTRACT_ID, ATTACHMENT_ID ) VALUES( ?, ? )"
    .setParameter(1, 13)
    .setParameter(2, 25) 
    .executeUpdate();
```

By default, it appears that hibernate is flushing my caches whether I request it or not.

```
2014-06-20 15:00:56,964 [http-bio-8880-exec-3] [127.0.0.1-5385277c1ecbbf5a] INFO  org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener - Session Metrics {
    70000 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    2731000 nanoseconds spent preparing 21 JDBC statements;
    11467000 nanoseconds spent executing 21 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
    28387000 nanoseconds spent executing 2 flushes (flushing a total of 18 entities and 17 collections);
    674000 nanoseconds spent executing 2 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 2 entities and 2 collections)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can control flush mode type for each query object through Query.setFlushMode.

"persistence provider is responsible for ensuring that all updates to the state of all entities in the persistence context which could potentially affect the result of the query are visible to the processing of the query. The persistence provider implementation may achieve this by flushing those entities to the database or by some other means."

Take a look at [FlushModeType](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/FlushModeType.html)